# How to display results from query with LinqToSQL

Tags: c#, wpf, select, linq-to-sql

I am stuck. I want to display a query result into a datagrid.

I have LinqToSQL class named : linq_to_sql.dbml

I have my datagrid :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="list_clients"></DataGrid>
```

And this is my code :

```
linq_to_sqlDataContext db = new linq_to_sqlDataContext();
var query = (from c in db.CLIENT select c);
list_clients.ItemsSource = query;
```

But every time I run my application, it doesn't work : System.InvalidCastException error

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `list_clients.ItemsSource = query;`. Then with the code stopped at that point, put the mouse cursor on "query" and check to see what it looks like.  It needs to be a collection.

Comment: What I have for tha value if null, and type is System.Collections.IEnumerable.

Comment: are you getting query as null?

Comment: Yes, my query is null. But I start another projet, very simple, i did another database and it works at the first time. I think my first error comes from the way  I had created my database with LinqToSQL class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `var query` does not contain your query result, it still has your query in sql format (you can put a breakpoint at this line and see the value of `query`), until you cast this query into some collection or datatable. In order to bind grid you need either collection type or datatable. Change this line:

```
list_clients.ItemsSource = query;
```

to

```
list_clients.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Adding `query.ToList();` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to populate your DataGrid by doing this:

```
public WindowDemo01()
{
    InitializeComponent(); // Make sure this occurs first so that your Datagrid is built before your ItemsSource is set.

    var query = (from c in db.CLIENT select new { Name = c.Name });    

    list_clients.ItemsSource = query.ToList();

}
```

I used a fieldname = "Name" because that is what my table had. You can use something else. You can also return more than one field.

Make sure that your CLIENT table in the database is the same one that the datacontext is being set to. You might have to work with the Server Explorer to get what you need.

I was never able to get the System.InvalidCastException  error that you had. I suspect that something else might be happening in you application.